# C# scan a folder and open files that have been created after a certain time

Tags: c#, file

I am writing a little program in C# that scans a folder and opens the files that have been created after 5.30pm after a button has been pressed on the program. This will also have to search within sub-folders.

I need a couple of solutions to point me in the correct direction as I'm not sure how I would do this.

This is part of a folder watcher program. The problem is when the user goes home the PC is switched off and there are files being created to the directory after 17.30. So I need a way for when the program is restarted in the morning it detects anything created after 17.30 and open them.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folderBrowser.ShowDialog();

        textBox1.Text = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
        filewatcher.Path = textBox1.Text;
        Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\COMPANY\\FOLDERWATCHER", "FOLDERPATH", textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String WatchFolder = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\COMPANY\\FOLDERWATCHER", "FOLDERPATH", "").ToString();

        textBox1.Text = WatchFolder;
        filewatcher.Path = WatchFolder;
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
            Hide();
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!e.FullPath.EndsWith("temp.temp"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have a Collection Form: " + e.Name);
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", e.FullPath);
        }
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
    }
}
```

This is my complete code above. I would like to use a button to open or show the files created after 17.30.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the **System.IO** namespace, it has everything you need.

the **DirectoryInfo** and **File** classes will do what you want.

Comment: FileInfo/Directory.CreationTime to be more precise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx

Comment: @PoweRoy: well I didn't want to make it TOO easy for him ;)

Comment: So SO is pretty much a place to have your homework done for you. At least, I'm getting that feeling when I look through some of these questions (people with single-digit reps).

Comment: After coming here, having the page load in less than a second, and then clicking the MSDN link and waiting and waiting for it to load, I thought I'd come back here and wish that the full answer was posted. Oh, looks like the MSDN page loaded now. Gotta go.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the recursive method you are looking for:

```
public static List<string> GetFilesCreatedAfter(string directoryName, DateTime dt)
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
    if (!directory.Exists)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Directory does not exist : " + directoryName);
    var files = new List<string>();
    files.AddRange(directory.GetFiles().Where(n => n.CreationTime > dt).Select(n=>n.FullName));
    foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directoryName))
    {
        files.AddRange(GetFilesCreatedAfter(subDirectory,dt));
    }
    return files;
}
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thank you for the Information, how could I write this using a button.

Comment: in the event handler of Click event of your button, call this method with desired directoryPath and DateTime. i.e. `var files = GetFilesCreatedAfter(folderBrowser.SelectedPath, new DateTime(2011,06,24,17,30,0));`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FileSystemWatcher` ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)) to detect files that have been created after pressing a button (while your application is running).

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = "C:\\YourDirectory";
watcher.Created += (sender, args) => {
    // File was created
}
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

This allows you to track files as they are created (while your application is running).

If you just want to get a list of all directories that were created in a specified time range (before your application was started), then you can search the directory tree using `Directory.GetDirectories` and `Directory.GetFiles`.

Comment: This is the correct way to get real time changes, but his question sounds like he needs to do this historically versus real time.

Comment: Hi The Directory.Getdirectories and Directory.GetFiles seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In place of datetime place you date and time value.

```
void DirSearch(string dir) 
{
    try 
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir)) 
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*")) 
            {
                if(DateTime.Compare(f.GetCreationTime, datetime))
                {
                    //files found            
                }
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```